# Deploy react node application on shared hosting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

I am trying to deploy my react node application using shared hosting and I am getting a blank page. All the solutions found are not working
Here's how my folder structure is in my cpanel's file manager;
in the public-html folder, I have everything that was in the build folder(static files and an index.html file)
I also have another folder where I have my server application and this is how I am trying to serve the static files :

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../client/public')))
```

I am assuming here is where the problem is but I have never done this before so can't figure out
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you add `"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/"`, property to package.json file ?

Comment: Yes. When the page is loading it actually loads as a react site